# Is my new Time Machine backup okay if my MacBook went to sleep during encryption?

Tags: backup, time-machine, encryption

I started a new Time Machine backup last night and enabled the third-party app Amphetamine to keep my machine awake for 9 hours. When I returned in the morning, it appeared that my MacBook went to sleep after those 9 hours, but Time Machine still read "Encrypting...".

Is my Time Machine okay, or do I need to wipe it and start again?

*After this, I ejected the Time Machine drive and plugged the it back into my Macbook when I got to work. It backed up a new 500 MB of files and went back to encrypting. This makes me think that perhaps Time Machine dealt with the MacBook going to sleep fine, but I want to make sure.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Time Machine backup is OK!

The encryption process is completely resumable, and it does so automatically.